# Enter comma-separated list of years, year islands, convert to list of years in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to validate a list of years and year ranges into a list of year.  For instance, if the user enters:

`1946, 1948, cat, 1950-1954, dog, 1960`

I want VBA to parse this as a list:

`1946, 1948, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1960`

I will then use the year to modify specific cells on a worksheet.

I can deal with the cats and dogs easily with by splitting on commas and then validating for numeric values when I use the list:

```
Sub customYearList
 customListEntry = InputBox("Enter list of years to activate")

 customList = Split(customListEntry, ",")

       For Each cYear In customList
          If IsNumeric(cYear) Then
               [[use the year to reference a WS.cell(myRow, cYear) ]]
          end if
       Next
End sub
```

I can't figure out how to also catch the dashes, and fill in in between.  Psuedocode for what I am picturing:

```
if cYear[i] = "-"
    act on all integer values from cYear[i-1] to cYear[i+1]
```

But my list referencing doesn't even have an index to modify like that.  And there would be some funny looping.

FWIW

- valid years will always be between 1946 and 2050.  All of those years are
  listed in row 13.
- The end goal is to change to value in row 12, immediately above the year, to a `1` if the year is in the custom list, or a `0` if it is not.

I am having trouble searching for this, because I can't think of how to describe it without using the overloaded term "range".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplishes what you're looking for but additional error control could be added to ensure no duplication in the year list if that is an issue. Sorting the end result is another option not tackled but there are many examples of a simple array sort.

```
Sub customYearList()
    Dim i As Long, mny As Long, mxy As Long, y As Long, customListEntry As String
    Dim tmp As Variant, customList As Variant, yearList As Variant

    mny = 1946: mxy = 2050
    customListEntry = InputBox("Enter list of years to activate")
    'customListEntry = Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Value

    customList = Split(customListEntry, ",")
    ReDim yearList(0)
    For i = LBound(customList) To UBound(customList)
        If IsNumeric(customList(i)) Then
            If CLng(customList(i)) >= mny And CLng(customList(i)) <= mxy Then
                yearList(UBound(yearList)) = CLng(customList(i))
                ReDim Preserve yearList(UBound(yearList) + 1)
            End If
        ElseIf CBool(InStr(1, customList(i), Chr(45))) Then
            tmp = Split(customList(i), Chr(45))
            If IsNumeric(tmp(LBound(tmp))) And IsNumeric(tmp(UBound(tmp))) Then
                For y = CLng(tmp(LBound(tmp))) To CLng(tmp(UBound(tmp)))
                    If y >= mny And y <= mxy Then
                        yearList(UBound(yearList)) = y
                        ReDim Preserve yearList(UBound(yearList) + 1)
                    End If
                Next y
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve yearList(UBound(yearList) - 1)

    Sheet1.Cells(3, "B").Resize(1, UBound(yearList) + 1) = yearList
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, that's really slick!  A lot for me to learn in here.  One little typ0:  The `Instr(i, customList(i)....` should start at `1`, not `i.`  It is searching through a string, which has 1 based positioning, not a list, which has 0-based positioning.  Without this change, it will crash if the very first item in the input is non-numeric.  With the change it works great - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for catchimg that!